# Extention of Lebesgue measure

Tags: lebesgue-measure

For $n \in \Bbb N$, can we extend the Lebesgue measure to some measure(or complete measure) on $\Bbb R^n$? Can we extent the Lebesgue measure to some measure on the power set of $\Bbb R^n$?  (The answer is negative for $n=3$, by using Banach- Tarski s paradox)
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Such measure is possible only for $n=1$ and $n=2$. If $n\ge 3$ than the Banach-Tarski's theorem (paradox) provides a counter-example, it is not for the case $n=3$ only.

Comment: It depends on the axiom of choice. If you assume it, then even for $n=1$ there exist non Lebesgue measurable sets, making extending Lebesgue measure to power set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ impossible.

Comment: Lebesgue measure may be extended, even to non-Lebesgue-measurable sets.

Comment: Banach-Tarski precludes a finitely-additive measure that is preserved by translations and rotations.  I wonder if ali means something different?

Comment: (Mher)Why you say that such measure exists for $n=1$ or $n=2$. In my question  a measuremeans that a  countabily additive function on a sigma-algebra.\\

Comment: (GEdgar) The cllasical version of Banach-Tarski theorem,  precludes a finitely-additive measure for $n=3$. But What happen when $n\neq 3$? For example can we extend the Lebesgue measure which is defined on  Lebesgue measurable sets of $\Bbb,$ to some measure on the power set of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: ((Whith many thanks for your answers.))